# Facebook graph API cannot retrieve data such as statuses of a non-friend profile (no mutual friends)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

first time on stackoverflow. Was wondering about this problem I am having as mentioned in the title, my application cannot retrieve any data via the API for any profiles that are non-related in anyway (no mutual friends either). Is this a known thing due to privacy settings or permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the rules you have to know, for example 100007110730790 is a non-friend id:

**Rule 1**. If the user turn platform **Off**:

[image]

```
 Facebook API wouldn't work at all:
```

[image]

**Rule 2.** If the platform is **ON** and user 100007110730790 does not provide **user_status** permission for your app, you can get the feed with have tagged with you:

[image]

[image]

**Updates:**

**if you are using your apps(not graph API explorer default app, this app wouldn't include activity feed!), you can also get public activity feed(add life event, change language, so on, even though he/she doesn't use the app at all!):**

**Update 10 jan 2014:**

**shared_story is included on this rule.**

[image]

**Rule 3.** If the platform is **ON** and user 100007110730790 does provide **user_status** permission for your app, you can get the status feed even though non-friend!:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**And using FQL:**

[image]

So, for albums/photos is the same, the non friend need to grant **user_photos** permission to the same APP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I guess. In any ways you shouldn't be able to retrieve something that is not normally visible to you. Looking aroudn Stackoverflow there are multiple threads with similar queries, so it seems like a known limitation.