# Why can't the Facebook Graph API access public posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, http-get

I know this question has been asked before, but I have yet to find a satisyfing answer. I want to access Facebook posts by two different users, let's call them Kenny and Stan.

- Both users have *posts that clearly are public* – I can see them through my regular user account even though I have no connections whatsoever with Kenny nor Stan.
- I know *I can access other users* public posts using the same method (see below).
- I can access Kenny's posts *via the Graph API Explorer*. I cannot access Stan's posts through any API means though.

But here's what happens when I use this method `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/posts?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET`:

**Kenny:** I can only see a limited amount of the "posts", namely all his new friends and other people's comments.

**Stan:** All that shows up is the empty data array `{"data": []}`.

**Third random user:** I get precisely what I expect, all the public posts.

What is the cause of these seemingly random responses? I suspect it has something to do with the users privacy settings, but I tried accessing their `/permissions` endpoint and got even more errors (yay Facebook).

PS. Using the access token that the Graph API Explorer generates, I am able to access Kenny's posts via a GET call to the Graph API. I don't know what to make of this.

Comment: Just to anticipate comments related to user tokens: I will not be able to let the users give my app permissions. I only want to read content that is already public.

Comment: You can read my asnwer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796713/facebook-graph-api-cannot-retrieve-data-such-as-statuses-of-a-non-friend-profile/20800153#20800153, even though it may not a satisyfing answer, but i hope can give you some idea about the limitation of Facebook API.

Comment: Users are able to specify that their data is not available to other people through applications. It is likely that Stan has changed this setting. You can see your own settings for this in the "Apps others use" section on the App Settings page - https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share&view