# Getting public posts of a random user from Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to get the latest posts of some random users (public posts of curse). I figured since they are public posts I don't need to ask permission from the owner. Here is my code:

```
function fetchUrl($url){
     return file_get_contents($url);
}

$profile_id = "4";

$app_id     = "****";
$app_secret = "****";
    
$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");

$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/posts?{$authToken}");
$feedarray   = json_decode($json_object , true );

foreach ( $feedarray as $feed_data )
{
    var_dump( $feed_data);
}
```

It returns some data about the user activities but nothing about the post!

Here is the example

this is my fb acc ( I rarely use it ), I've just posted a post ( test3 )
https://www.facebook.com/Hereticcc

when I run this code with my account id

```
$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/posts?{$authToken}&limit=50");
$feedarray   = json_decode($json_object , true );
foreach ( $feedarray['data'] as $k=>$v )
{
    /// var_dump( $v['story']);
    echo  $v['story']; echo '<br />';
}
```

here is what I get! no sign of the post that I've just added only likes and friendships

```
Mj Tb Z likes Facebook Developers.
Mj Tb Z and Ahmad Masajedi are now friends.
Mj Tb Z and Di M AH are now friends.
Mj Tb Z likes Cult of Luna.
Mj Tb Z likes a link.
Mj Tb Z likes a status.
Mj Tb Z likes a link.
Mj Tb Z and Eh San Mans are now friends.
Mj Tb Z likes a link.
Mj Tb Z likes Mist Within.
Mj Tb Z likes Filmhaa.
Mj Tb Z likes a link.
Mj Tb Z and Mamad RJ are now friends.
Mj Tb Z likes a link.
Mj Tb Z is now using Facebook in English (US).
Mj Tb Z is now friends with Mushu Khoshbakht and Samin Zavarkesh.
Mj Tb Z likes a photo.
Mj Tb Z updated his cover photo.
Mj Tb Z and Mohammad Khoshbakht are now friends.
```

---

I've tried FQL

here is my code

```
$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");

echo $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
        . 'fql?q=SELECT+message+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=4'
        . '&' . $authToken;
        
echo '<br />';
$fql_query_result = fetchUrl($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
    
echo '<pre>';
print_r("query results:");
print_r($fql_query_obj);
echo '</pre>';
```

Here is the result:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+message+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=4&access_token=284654551659478|D7T6A1uMSr1Qm1LLFBB9CQk_vK8

query results:Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: +1 Your syntax is completely right and should work as charm! notice `'story' => string 'Mark Zuckerberg likes a life event.' (length=35)`

Comment: @AdamAzad i wnat to get his posts or his entries , right now all i get is his status update , likes, friendships .... where are the posts ?

Comment: Unless the user grant the user_status permission to the same APP, there's no way to retrieve posts. Take a look my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796713/facebook-graph-api-cannot-retrieve-data-such-as-statuses-of-a-non-friend-profile/20800153#20800153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read the feed of posts (including their status updates which are public) for a random user without his/her permission. You need a valid [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens) from a user with a `read_stream` permission in order to do that.

With a valid Access Token, you can achieve this for a particular user or his/her friends by using an FQL query on the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table. You can use a query like:

```
SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = {User_ID} LIMIT 50
```

Or, if you particularly concerned about the statuses of a user or his/her friends, you can use [status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/) table like:

```
SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid = {User_ID} LIMIT 50
```

---

There is however a way to read the stream of user status updates and page status updates as they are posted to Facebook. This can be done by using the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/). But this will only include status updates that have their privacy set to ‘public’ are included in the stream. Also, you cannot apply to use the API at this time as its access is limited.

Comment: i want to get his posts or his entries , right now all i get is his status update , likes, friendships ....

Comment: The result will also contain the posts if the user had made it public. I am able to obtain the posts using this query.

Comment: maybe it has changed since , i've edited my post with an example

Comment: Oh! So you meant statuses. No, you can't read statuses for some random user. The user must have granted a user_status permission to your APP. Only then you can read the statuses.

Comment: I've just edited the answer. Try it out using FQL on Graph explorer. It's working fine for random users but for some reason, it's not showing your test posts!

Comment: i've tried fql but i got nothing , please take a look at my code and see if i'm doing it wrong (i've edited my question and added fql code)

Comment: Hi! It turns out that you cannot do that for a random user. I've updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Hi again! Did you find another way to do that?

Comment: Based on my experience, it's only possible using the public feed API. And, access to that API is limited.

Comment: what if user grants access to my app ? like if a user logins to his account with my app ?

Comment: Yes, then you can. You must have a valid access token with a `read_stream` permission.